# Map key and value to an array of strings

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

In my angular app, I am using a Table, where I have to map the row value(an array of strings) to a key-value pair. Please guide me regarding this.

HTML

```
<table  mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="data">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="bottom-primary-color"> Data </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" width="150px" > {{displayData[row.data]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

TS

```
get displayData(): Record<string, string> {
    return {
        test1: 'testtest1',
        test2: 'testtest2',
        test3: 'testtest3',
    };
}
```

I want to achieve this.

`data = [test1, test2, test3];`

I want to map the array `data` with `displayData` object and display
`testtest1, testtest2, testtest3` instead of `test1,test2,test3` for my user.

I am able to map the key-value pair only for the first element in the array. How can I map key-value pairs for all the elements of the array?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63373857/4243050) you can use the ngFor statement to iterate over the keys of your object like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(your_json_object)">
    <td>{{your_json_object[key]}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

With this approach you can use displayData() to fill your datasource and then get a list of the keys. Here you can access your data with `your_json_object[key]` which will return you the value with the key name.

EDIT: Just read your post again and noticed that you want to use the data-array to define the order of the values. Since you managed to do this for the first value only what is missing should be the ngFor as well. Try to add this in your container should fix that problem.